# How to pass this in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

**Current Code**

```html
<header :class="{ 'active': scrollY > 900 }">
  <span>header</span>
</header>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      scrollY: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll() {
      this.scrollY = window.scrollY
    }
  }
}
```

---

I would like to pass `<header>` itself, like

```html
<header :class="{ 'active': this }">
```

In Vue.js, how can I do it?
Should I use `ref` ?

Comment: What do you want to do with this in the child component? In my opinion, it's not a good practice to do such a thing.

Comment: Simply use a computed property.

Comment: is header a html element or Vue component? If it's a component, you can set the class name in it..